# Parsing JSON with GSON is not working. Variables are empty

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSON string like this:

```
[
{
"locationID" : "1",        
"name" : "Trdinova lokacija",
"address":{
    "address1": "Trdinova ulica 9",
    "address2": "",
    "zipCode":  "1000",
    "city":     "Ljubljana",
    "country":  "Slovenija"
},
"geoLocation":{
    "latitude": 46.05570,
    "longitude": 14.50705,
},
"workingTime" : "8:00 - 18:00",
"parkingPlaces" : 10,
"href": "/locations/{id}",
"numberOfCarsOnLocation" : 10
},
{
"locationID" : "2",        
"name" : "Dunajska lokacija",
"address":{
    "address1": "Dunajska cesta 140",
    "address2": "",
    "zipCode":  "1000",
    "city":     "Ljubljana",
    "country":  "Slovenija"
},
"geoLocation":{
    "latitude": 46.07980,
    "longitude": 14.51309,
},
"workingTime" : "8:00 - 18:00",
"parkingPlaces" : 10,
"href": "/locations/{id}",
"numberOfCarsOnLocation" : 10
}
]
```

And a Location class like this:

```
public class Location {
    private String locationID;
    private String name;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String workingTime;
    private String href;
    private String distance;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    private int parkingPlaces;
    private int numberOfCarsOnLocation;
}
```

I am trying to parse it like this:

```
locationArrayList = gson.fromJson(responseString, new TypeToken<List<ACLocation>>(){}.getType());
```

I don't get any errors, but when I try to access values (for example address1), it returns null. Only top level values (like locationID, name...) are working. But if I try to access the lower level values (address1, latitude...) it is returning null.

I am guessing that I can't read the lower level values directly into variables, but how else should this be done correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Create your classes from [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Your also have an extra comma at the end in your geoLocation field.

Comment: @Tarun thank you very much. This looks useful. And I'm aware of the extra comma. I copied the not-fixed version of JSON accidentaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your address1, address2... fields are inside a JSON object, so in your `Location` class, you must have an `address` attribute like :

```
public class Location {
    private String locationID;
    private String name;
    private Address address
    ...
}
```

And the `Address` class looks like :

```
public class Address {
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
}
```

The reasoning is the same for the `geoLocation` field.